# Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, hosting

mysql_error пишет Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'  но у меня только таблица messages и поле message[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",5000);/
</script>
<body>

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $sql = "insert into `messages` (`message`) values ('".$_POST['message']."')";
  mysql_query($sql);

}
$sql = "select message from `messages` where 1 order by id desc";
$res = mysql_query($sql);


if($res)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
     printf("<div>%s</div>",$row->message);
    }
}
else
{ 
  echo "<p><b>Error: ".mysql_error()."</b></p>";
  exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну так вам и пишут, что неизвестная колонка `id` в условии сортировки, потому что такой колонки в таблице нет, а вы пишите `order by id desc`.......логично же

Comment: И вообще, это ваше `order by id desc` - какая-то не хорошая штука! `last_insert_id` в php+mysql используется, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Cпасибо........

Answer (score 1):

Решается созданием поле id в таблице messages

Comment: я на всякий случай ещё раз повторю, что *"это ваше `order by id desc` - какая-то не хорошая штука! `last_insert_id` в php+mysql используется, насколько я знаю. "*

Comment: @4per Хорошо я заменил у себя

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать поле `id`.
Ошибка возникает потому что ты сортируешь по несуществующим поле `id`.